# How to fix "Warning: Prop className did not match" when using UIkit and NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uikit, next.js

The warning appears when using [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/) to style components in NextJS.

To reproduce:

1. Create new nextjs app: `npx create-next-app {app-name}`
2. `cd {app-name} && npm i`
3. Replace the code in `pages/index.js` with the snippet below (2nd part)
4. Create `components/layout.js` and add the snippet below (1st part)
5. `npm run dev` and go to http://localhost:3000
6. You'll see the warning in the console

The app functions normally, but the warnings are really a turn-off

```js
// components/layout.js (1st part)

import Head from "next/head";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {/* UIkit CSS */}
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.5/dist/css/uikit.min.css"
        />
        <title>NextJs App</title>

        {/* UIkit JS */}
        <script
          async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.5/dist/js/uikit.min.js"
        />
        <script
          async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.5/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"
        />
      </Head>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;


// pages/index.js (2nd part)
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" data-uk-grid>
        <div>
          <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">Item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The error on the console appears as shown in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the way I was loading the scripts.

When I changed the script attribute `async` to `defer` the Warning was gone and the page was compiled without any warnings